# PHP Json_decode Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to decode a portion of a json code in PHP. The json looks something like:

```
"title":"A Title Here",
"images":[

{
    "coverType":"fanart",
    "url":"some_random_file_here.jpg"
},
{
    "coverType":"banner",
    "url":"another_random_file_here.jpg"
},
{
    "coverType":"poster",
    "url":"yet_another_random_file_here.jpg"
}

],
```

I want to get the **url** that is under the **"coverType":"banner"**

I can easily parse the title with the following code:

```
$itemNr = 0;
            foreach($json as $item) {
                $mytitle = $item['title'];
                echo $mytitle;
$itemNr++;
```

How would my code look like using the same concept. Please note that I have simplified the code of JSON. The actual php for some items not shown on my code above look something like:

```
$somevariable = $item['series']['tvdbId'];
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

H.

Comment: `foreach ($item['images'] as $v)`

Comment: Thank you. What I am trying to do is to ONLY return the "url" value under the coverType: banner. I want to ignore the others. I was Guessing it would be something like: `$myurl = $item['images']['coveType:banner']'[url'];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can access the images key, then:

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "title":"A Title Here",
    "images":[
        {
            "coverType":"fanart",
            "url":"some_random_file_here.jpg"
        },
        {
            "coverType":"banner",
            "url":"another_random_file_here.jpg"
        },
        {
            "coverType":"poster",
            "url":"yet_another_random_file_here.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
JSON;

$json = json_decode($json);
print_r($json);

foreach ($json->images as $img)
{
    if ( $img->coverType == "banner" )
    {
        echo 'Image Cover Type: ' .$img->coverType .'<br/>';
        echo 'URL: ' .$img->url .'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Gives:

Image Cover Type: banner

URL: another_random_file_here.jpg

UPDATE:

The JSON file you link to seems invalid, missing braces after each series. Here's the corrected JSON, and code:

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
[
{
    "series": {
      "title": "Brooklyn Nine-Nine",
      "images": [
        {
          "coverType": "fanart",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/269586-15.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "banner",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/269586-g3.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "poster",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/posters/269586-13.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "year": 2013
    }
},
{
    "series": {
      "title": "The Middle",
      "images": [
        {
          "coverType": "fanart",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/95021-16.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "banner",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/95021-g14.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "poster",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/posters/95021-8.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "year": 2009
    }
},
{
    "series": {
      "title": "New Girl",
      "images": [
        {
          "coverType": "fanart",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/fanart/original/248682-43.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "banner",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/248682-g20.jpg"
        },
        {
          "coverType": "poster",
          "url": "http://thetvdb.com/banners/posters/248682-14.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "year": 2011
    }
}
]
JSON;

$json = json_decode($json);
// echo '<pre>' .print_r($json, 1) .'</pre>';

foreach ($json as $item)
{
    echo 'Title: ' .$item->series->title .'<br/>';
    foreach ($item->series->images as $img)
    {
        if ( $img->coverType == "banner" )
        {
            echo 'Image Cover Type: ' .$img->coverType .'<br/>';
            echo 'URL: ' .$img->url .'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Gives:

Title: Brooklyn Nine-Nine
Image Cover Type: banner
URL: http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/269586-g3.jpg

Title: The Middle
Image Cover Type: banner
URL: http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/95021-g14.jpg

Title: New Girl
Image Cover Type: banner
URL: http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/248682-g20.jpg

Comment: Thank you Stuart. As I describe in my comment above, I only want to get the value for the url that is under coverType:banner. Basically i want a variable that will return me the value that in my example would be "another_random_file_here.jpg". I have no idea what this value will be as they will vary greatly. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry Stuart. Not a big expert... My json string will contain may entries, I have created a more expanded sample of the JSON output. [See Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kpxVYFF1). Not sure how to create my code so I can get a "title" for each entry, a banner "url" for each entry. I just do not understand how your answer will relate to the **Title** and other data I need to scrape for each of the array entries. A million thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll update my answer. Your JSON is not valid either - there are missing braces to close each series...

Comment: Thank you Stuart.... This was the answer. I am very grateful for your help. I have been trying for hours. The invalid JSON is probably because I I simplified the code for clarity and I am sure I deleted a few things. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the variable jsondecoded,
$json[images][1]->coverType;

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?  I'm missing if it's another question or an answer.

Comment: '$json=$json_decode($variablenam); ' ' $json[images][1]->coverType;  '   see  in json you acces each by objects like u could have did images->covertype but as u can see the covertype data is in array so for that we use image[array pos postion of covertype]->covertype;